# Back up Oracle db gives error

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

Here is my command to backup database :

```
RMAN> backup as backupset database plus archivelog;
```

Here are the errors I get :

```
Starting backup at 18-APR-17
ORACLE error from target database:
ORA-00258: manual archiving in NOARCHIVELOG mode must identify log

using channel ORA_DISK_1
specification does not match any archived log in the repository
backup cancelled because there are no files to backup
Finished backup at 18-APR-17

Starting backup at 18-APR-17
using channel ORA_DISK_1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of backup plus archivelog command at 04/18/2017 11:59:03
RMAN-06149: cannot BACKUP DATABASE in NOARCHIVELOG mode
```

I'm very new to Oracle, so I couldn't solve this problem myself. Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: First follow Brian Leach's answer and then please also remove archivelogs after they have been backed up. For example: `backup database;` `backup archivelog all delete input;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot backup the archivelogs because you are in 'NOARCHIVELOG' mode. When your database is in NOARCHIVELOG mode, the only way to back it up with RMAN is to shut it down and do a cold backup.

If you want to put your database into archive log mode, as DBA from a sqlplus command prompt:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
alter database archivelog;
alter database open;
```